# react js How to keep the initial data saved after applying the fitler on array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React JS based UI and facing an issue wiht data .

1. I fetch data from an API and store it in an initial value by using useState hook.
2. Then I use useEffect to store it in 'lists' via setLists()

```
const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
  
  const url = "https://domain/api/all";
  fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(response=> {
    setLists(response.json.list);
  });
```

3. Now I am able to use map to enter data in a table
4. Lists is an array object that has multiple values in it and I want t filter the table based on age and country

```
let [ageList, setAgeList] = useState([]);
let [countryList, setcoutryList] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
 var newList = lists.filter(e=> e.age === age); 
  setList(newList)

},[age])


useEffect(()=>{

  setlist(lists.filter(e=> e.country === country))

},[country])
```

With this method first attempt of filter works fine by both Age and Country but when I change the value of the filter for age or country then I get empty array which is expected as the new lists variable has entered with last filtered country/age

How can I get over this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, when you overwrite your previous state with the filtered state, you lose the previous state forever. The solution here is to keep the initial value of `lists` and create a new variable for your filtered lists. Something like this:

```
const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
const [ageFilter, setAgeFilter] = useState("");
const [countryFilter, setcountryFilter] = useState("");

const url = "https://domain/api/all";

fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response=> {
    setLists(response.json.list);
  });

let filteredByCountryAndAge = listfilter((listItem) => {
  return (listItem.country === countryFilter && listItem.age === ageFilter);
});
```

(or however else you are filtering it).

The point being, do not change the value of `lists` after it is set with the entire list. When filtering, assign the criteria by which you are filtering to state variables, but assign the filtered data to a variable—NOT a state variable.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. It did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control over the fetched data? If so, the obvious solution would be to change the datamodel server side.

If not, I would suggest storing the initial response in a mutable object from `useRef`.

*Edit*

```
const [lists, setLists] = useState([]);
const cache = useRef([]);

useEffect(()=>{
  
  const url = "https://domain/api/all";
  fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(response=> {
    cache.current = response.json.list;
    setLists(response.json.list);
  });
});
```